# Zabbix Upgrade to 5.0 database upgrade failed

Tags: mysql, zabbix

I'm trying to upgrade my Zabbix Server today (MariaDB). Current version is 4.4, I want to update it to 5.0

Installation went well. When I start the zabbix-server process, the database starts upgrading, and it then stops with the following error message

```
[Z3005] query failed: [1025] Error on rename of './zabbix/items' to './zabbix/#sql2-6a6-347' (errno: 152) [alter table items drop foreign key c_items_1]
  3891:20200525:110755.747 database upgrade failed
```

Im trying connect to MySQL and run command:

```
alter table items ADD CONSTRAINT `c_items_1` FOREIGN KEY (`itemid`) REFERENCES `items` (`itemid`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

And have error:

```
#1025 - Error on rename of './zabbix/#sql-6a6_2b9' to './zabbix/items' (errno: 150)
```

What to do with it?

Comment: `$ perror 152` -> `MySQL error code 152: Cannot delete a parent row`,
`$ perror 150` -> `MySQL error code 150: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation was decided by creating a key constraint `c_items_1`. The first time I created a query:

```
alter table items ADD CONSTRAINT `c_items_1` FOREIGN KEY (`itemid`) REFERENCES `items` (`itemid`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But I made a mistake in REFERENCES. Having looked at the key restrictions in the backup database, I received a request

```
alter table items ADD CONSTRAINT `c_items_1` FOREIGN KEY (`hostid`) REFERENCES `zabbix`.`hosts` (`hostid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Thank for help!

Answer (score 0):

In my situation this error was caused by a bug: [ZBX-16308](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-16308).